# why delete() function is not deleting the value after filtering the collection in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, module

I am trying to delete a data from the table.

I am using this code snippet

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {  
                $cat->delete();
        }
```

and it is deleting the complete table.

but I dont want to delete the complete table so I filter the data with some attribute and tried this code

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', $articleId);  
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
                $cat->delete();
        }
```

but it is not deleting anything.
How can I delete the data according to some field.

Comment: Make sure your collection contains at least an object.

Comment: What do you mean it's deleting the whole table?

Comment: @Marius my collection contains only an array.

Comment: @moose whole table means the complete table data not the structure

Comment: So you'd like to basically just truncate the table?

Comment: @waseem. This means you don't have anything to delete. Your filtering did not produce any results. check with `$categoryModel->count()`. If that is 0 then nothing to delete.

Comment: no not truncate the table just to delete the value with the article_id='any id' not any other value for the article_id

Comment: yeah @marius you are right it actually prints 0, but I dont know why, when I use this filtering in the edit action it shows the result but not here, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addFieldToFilter` method is incorrect, you need to type:

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', array('eq'=>$articleId));  
    foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
            $cat->delete();
    }
```

Or as an alternative, you could go the direct SQL route:

```
public function delete_articles($article_id_value){
    $connection = $this->_getConnection('core_write');
    $table = $this->_getTableName('my_table_name');
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE `article_id` = ?';
    $connection->query($sql, $article_id_value);
}

public function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

public function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}
```

Comment: your first method is not producing any thing the result is same but i didn't try the second one let me try that option too.

Comment: And you're sure that there are values in your table with 'any_id' as the `article_id` ? (`echo count($categoryModel);` after the selection before the foreach)

Comment: yeah ofcourse definitely.

Comment: What does the count value say after doing the selection?

Comment: I already said it in the comment above. I didn't understand also, it is showing 0,

Comment: I got it now thanks all for your help thanks very much.

Comment: Great to hear, what was the issue?

Comment: well, when marius says to count the result and it is showing 0, then i recheck the value in the variable, it is collecting the wrong id from the session, but now i fixed it. thanks again for all your help.